# How to fix an N-channel MOSFET that's always on, without using resistors

Tags: voltage, mosfet, nmos

First things first: I'm very new to electronics

Getting right into it: I am trying to use an N-channel MOSFET as a LED strip light switch, with 12V at 1.5A supplied to the source and 4.5V from a battery supplied to the gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKTcrP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I find that even without connecting the wires to my battery, my mosfet seems to allow flow from source to drain.

I'm hoping that someone may be able to tell me what is wrong and how I can fix it. The MOSFET I have is an [FQU13N10L](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/FQU13N10L-D-1810105.pdf).

In addition I also have some particulars about the answers:

- This circuit is just a test for a larger project which involves about 60 MOSFETs on a breadboard, which cramps my breadboard. I need a solution that does not involve resistors or capacitors that will cramp up a lot of space on my bread board;
- Second, if needed I can change the 4.5V to be 3V or 3.3V by using different batteries;
- Third, it may be important to note that the gate voltage of 4.5V is controlled by a GPIO pin on a PIC microcontroller. I do not know if that matters but I need nothing to go through the 4.5 lines that may hurt the microcontroller, which can not handle 12V.

I apologize if I sound demanding in this, I am just trying to be as clear in my purpose as possible, thank you for all your answers

Comment: A resistor is the obvious answer so maybe explain why your title says "without using resistors"?

Comment: @Andyaka Because I do not want them, if you require an explanation please refer to my first bullet point

Comment: @KidWithComputer "I do not want them" isn't really a good enough reason. Yeah, they may take up some space, but if they are required, then searching for shortcuts may well leave you with a project that doesn't work properly. Best to just do it correctly from the start and find a way to deal with the cramped space. You can always connect breadboards together to give yourself more space. But resistors will be the correct way to do it.

Comment: @MCG are you telling me that there is absolutely no other solution than to use a resistor?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not having resistors from gate to source will cause the gate to float and once turned on, the MOSFET will take ages to turn off.

Comment: @Andyaka What does it mean for a gate to float

Comment: [What happens when a MOSFETs gate is left open?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45494/what-happens-when-a-mosfets-gate-is-left-open)

Comment: @KidWithComputer floating means it isn't high or low, it can "float" anywhere between those 2 points, so it is undefined. That is why we use resistors to pull the voltage high or low so we know for sure the state of the pin to stop undefined behaviour

Comment: @KidWithComputer there is no proper solution that will give you consistent results. Resistors are the way to do it

Comment: @MCG What about the solutions proposed in the two answers to this question? Also what if I just connect it to ground via a wire instead of a resistor

Comment: A switch will take up more room that a resistor, and using internal resistors of a microcontroller doesn't always work consistently for pulling up/down as they are usually rather weak, and not every pin on every microcontroller has that capability. As for using a wire, that will work. But as soon as that switch is closed, you're essentially shorting whatever is driving the gate to ground, so thats not gonna work

Comment: @MCG Ok thank you for the detailed explanation

Comment: @MCG just as a proof to myself I tried connecting the wire to the -12V and the gate, completely disconnecting the battery from the breadboard, but the thing still lit up! What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Nobody else commented on this so I am. You say in your question "I find that even without connecting the wires to my battery, my mosfet seems to allow flow from source to drain." That may be a typo. But an N-channel MOSFET has a built-in diode that will always allow current to flow from source to drain (as long as the voltage is more than half a volt or so). In your schematic you show the MOSFET connected up correctly such that current will flow from drain to source.

Comment: The gate voltage on a mosfet always needs to be controlled (Vgs, I mean). It doesn't always need a resistor. For example, if you drive the gate from a microcontroller ouput and the output always drives either high or low, then you don't necessarily need a resistor from gate to source. There could be a moment during power on of the microcontroller when the output is not driven and that could cause problems for you. You kind of have to evaluate on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: _"is controlled by a GPIO pin on a PIC microcontroller"_ Which PIC?

Comment: @BruceAbbott a 16F15345

Comment: @mkeith if current is always flowing how do I stop it?

Comment: First try connecting the source to the gate. That should turn off your MOSFET. If that doesn't work, maybe your MOSFET is faulty. Or maybe you have it hooked up reversed. In an N-channel MOSFET current can always flow from source to drain, but it will not flow from drain to source unless the gate voltage is high (compared to source). So if you connected the source to the LED and drain to ground, that is a mistake.

Comment: How do you intend to control 60 MOSFETs with an MCU that only has 18 I/O pins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving the gate floating (when the switch is open) can lead to what you are seeing; the gate is high-impedance and charge can accumulate on it, switching the FET.

It needs a pull-down resistor on its gate to make things predictable (explicitly driving the gate to 0 V when the switch is open), space or no space on your breadboard.

I don't know about the PIC you are using; it may have internal pull-up and/or pull-down resistors you can activate in code, or actively drive its pins high and low.

You could use this instead of external pull-down resistors when you drive the gates directly from the PIC's IO pins. It would leave the gates in an undefined state until the PIC has booted up and has configured the pins, though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: Note that resistors can come in packs, with 8 or more resistors in a pack, saving space.

Comment: Note that an internal pulling resistor will typically only work when the MCU is programmed and has completed booting up to the point in code where it is configured.

Comment: @Chris-Stratton: Yes, added that to answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when using the MOSFET, you cannot leave the GATE open.  It's a VERY high impedance input that controls a very high-gain device.  So leaving it open allows anything and everything to happen to it.

This pin is the GATE:

[image]

Normally you will tie it to Vcc or GND via a resistor to keep it in the state you want when you are not driving it.  In your case you have a simple switch that will drive it to 4.5V.  So a resistor to GND is appropriate to keep the MOSFET OFF until you want it to turn ON.

Alternatively, if for some strange reason you really don't want to use a resistor that costs a tiny amount, you could use a SPDT switch that connects the GATE to GND when it's not connected to your 4.5V source.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, what is meant by leaving a gate open? Is that just not connecting anything to it? What would happen if I simply connected it via a wire to ground?

Comment: I updated my answer with the GATE identified.

Comment: To the OP: If the gate is wired directly to ground, and the source is also connected to ground, then the transistor will not turn on under any circumstances. In order to turn on the transistor you will have to remove the gate ground wire and drive the gate high. This may be obvious. It is hard to tell what people know and don't know. Please don't take offense.

Comment: @mkeith I really appreciate the help, but mostly I appreciate the understanding, no offense taken my dude.